# Не могу понять смысл кода в Python: counts[label] = X[y == label].sum(axis=0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

В следующем коде мне непонятно что делает код `X[y==label].sum(axis=0)`:

```
X = np.array([[0,1,0,1],
              [1,0,1,1],
              [0,0,0,1],
              [1,0,1,0]])

y = np.array([0,1,0,1])

counts = {}
for label in np.unique(y):
     counts[label] = X[y == label].sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поэтапно:

```
>>> np.unique(y)
array([0, 1])
```

т.е. просто получаем уникальные значения из массива y

Пусть `label = 0`:

```
>>> label = 0

>>> y == label
array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

т.е. из исходного массива `y` получили массив-фильтр. `True` в этом массиве там, где в массиве `y` значение элемента равно `label` (в данном случае - 0).

```
>>> X[y == label]
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Тут просто оставляем строки, в соответствии с тем, где в массиве `y` значения равны `label`.

```
>>> X[y==label].sum(axis=0)
array([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

Суммируются значения по оси 0 (т.е. по столбцам).

Дальше в цикле по двум разным фильтрам (для `y == 0` и `y == 1`) итоги записываются в словарь `counts`:

```
>>> counts = {}

>>> for label in np.unique(y):
...     counts[label] = X[y == label].sum(axis=0)

>>> counts
{0: array([0, 1, 0, 2]), 1: array([2, 0, 2, 1])}
```

Comment: Тип `np.array` переопределяет `__eq__`, чтобы фишка с `y == label` работала через нативные операторы?

Comment: @gil9red, не только `__eq__`, другие операторы сравнения тоже переопределены, поэтому можно делать например `z[z > 0].sum()` чтобы посчитать сумму положительных элементов.

Comment: Круто, впервые увидев этот трюк, я тогда сильно удивился, мол как этот фильтр работает, если результат всегда True/False, а потом уже дошло :D

Comment: Спасибо, дошло наконец, что код X[y==label] оставляет из массива Х "трушные" строки

Answer (score 1):

[@insolor отлично объяснил, что делает указанный в вопросе код.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703812/211923)

Я бы хотел добавить альтернативный (чуть более "numpy"-ный) вариант решения, без применения циклов:

```
In [284]: counts = np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, 0, X[y == label])

In [285]: counts
Out[285]:
array([[0, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 1]], dtype=int64)

In [286]: counts[0]
Out[286]: array([0, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)

In [287]: counts[1]
Out[287]: array([2, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```