# В коде ниже какую роль выполняет условие y_xor == 1? (Логическое индексирование в Numpy.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
X_xor = np.random.randn(200, 2)
y_xor = np.logical_xor(X_xor[:, 0] > 0,
                       X_xor[:, 1] > 0)
y_xor = np.where(y_xor, 1, -1)

plt.scatter(X_xor[y_xor == 1, 0],
            X_xor[y_xor == 1, 1],
            c='b', marker='x',
            label='1')
plt.scatter(X_xor[y_xor == -1, 0],
            X_xor[y_xor == -1, 1],
            c='r',
            marker='s',
            label='-1')
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Не могу понять смысл кода в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/703786/1365)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это логическое индексирование ([boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)) в Numpy.

```
y_xor == 1
```

возвращает массив `boolean` равный по длине числу строк в `X_xor` - это позволяет использовать логическое индексирование.

```
In [23]: X_xor.shape
Out[23]: (200, 2)

In [24]: (y_xor == 1).shape
Out[24]: (200,)

In [27]: (y_xor == 1).dtype
Out[27]: dtype('bool')
```

Т.е. следующая конструкция вернёт массив значений, состоящий из строк с индексами, для которых выполняется условие (`y_xor == 1`) и только из первого столбца (столбец с индексом `0`):

```
X_xor[y_xor == 1, 0] 
#                 ^
#                 |________  столбцы: выбираем значения из столбца с индексом `0`
#     ^^^^^^^^^^
#          |_______________   строки: выбираем те строки в матрице `X_xor`, 
#                             где значение `y_xor` с тем же индексом равен `1`
```

---

Примеры:

Исходная матрица:

```
In [39]: X = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)

In [40]: X
Out[40]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

выбрать те строки, для которых в индексирующем массиве находится значение `True`:

```
In [41]: X[[False,True,False,True]]
Out[41]:
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

те же строки, но но только второй (с индексом `1`) столбец:

```
In [42]: X[[False,True,False,True], 1]
Out[42]: array([ 4, 10])
```

PS длина индексирующего массива должна совпадать с размерностью индексируемой оси (`axis=0` - строки в примере выше)

Answer (score 1):

В коде `y_xor == 1` бесполезен так как `y_xor` уже булевый массив, который как есть можно в качестве индекса использовать — [Boolean or “mask” index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). К примеру:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
>>> a
array([-2, -1,  0,  1,  2])
>>> a[a > 0]
array([1, 2])
```

`a > 0` создаёт массив, той же формы, что и сам `a` массив, со значениями `True` в тех местах, где элементы массива `a` больше нуля. `a[a > 0]` возвращает массив с положительными элементами из `a`.

Код в вопросе можно упростить:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
X_xor = np.random.randn(200, 2)
y_xor = np.logical_xor(X_xor[:, 0] > 0,
                       X_xor[:, 1] > 0)
not_y_xor = np.logical_not(y_xor)

plt.scatter(X_xor[y_xor, 0],
            X_xor[y_xor, 1],
            c='b', marker='x',
            label='1')
plt.scatter(X_xor[not_y_xor, 0],
            X_xor[not_y_xor, 1],
            c='r',
            marker='s',
            label='-1')
plt.show()
```

[image: numpy scatter plot]

Подробно: [Boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).